# Why Prerender Error happens in Next.js / Vercel?

Tags: next.js, vercel

It does not happen locally no error for `yarn build` only in Vercel.

I got this `cryptic` error:

```
Error occurred prerendering page "/pf/program". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
01:22:05.392    Error: The provided export path '/pf/program' doesn't match the '/[organizationShortId]/program/[programId]' page.
01:22:05.392    Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/export-path-mismatch
01:22:05.392        at /vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/export/worker.js:80:27
01:22:05.392        at Span.traceAsyncFn (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/trace/trace.js:79:26)
01:22:05.392        at Object.exportPage (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/export/worker.js:28:27)
01:22:05.392        at execFunction (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/jest-worker/processChild.js:1:2828)
01:22:05.392        at execHelper (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/jest-worker/processChild.js:1:2486)
01:22:05.392        at execMethod (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/jest-worker/processChild.js:1:2574)
01:22:05.393        at process.messageListener (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/jest-worker/processChild.js:1:1284)
01:22:05.394        at process.emit (node:events:513:28)
01:22:05.394        at emit (node:internal/child_process:937:14)
01:22:05.394        at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
01:22:05.866    info  - Generating static pages (124/124)
01:22:05.867    
01:22:05.867    > Build error occurred
01:22:05.870    Error: Export encountered errors on following paths:
01:22:05.870        /[organizationShortId]/program/[programId]: /pf/program
01:22:05.870        at /vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/export/index.js:395:19
01:22:05.870        at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

yes, I have a page here:

pages/[organizationShortId]/program/[programId]/index.tsx

but `program` was not changed at all!

I have changed only these, not `..program` in this commit. Maybe Vercel updated his Node version?!

[image]

I have upgraded all the packages in `package.json`, did `yarn`.